# DB locks when multiple spark sqoop process is running parallelly

Tags: java, sqoop

I am scooping the data from HDFS folders files into PostgreSQL DB table using Java.

What the scenario here is when multiple process is running and trying to insert into the same table, the process is suddenly stuck or take too long time.

How can I handle DB locks here, for eg:

**Process1** takes 10 minutes, but when **Process2** runs parallelly **process1** takes around more than an hour, so either I have to force kill it or it fails. I want to do something like if already a process is running I want process2 to wait.
Should it be on the DB side or in the code?

Comment: We would probably need to know more about your table structure (table, indices) and the data your parallel processes are loading into it - you must be hitting lock contention on the table end somehow - and that would be what you want to avoid...